Match index of two dataframes:
I have a dataframes like



X
Y




0
1


0
125


1
65


1
59


2
28



and so on and another dataframe like



index
lat
lon




0
90.0
0.0


1
90.0
12.5


2
90.0
25.0


3
90.0
37.5


4
90.0
50.0



I want to match the first df1['X'] column with the second df2['index'] and update the first dataframe. My output should look like



X
lat
lon
Y




0
90.0
0.0
1


0
90.0
0.0
125


1
90.0
12.5
65


1
90.0
12.5
59


2
90.0
25.0
28


..
..
..




and so on. The two dataframes have different lengths. Any lead?

You can use merge():
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
    'Y': [1, 125, 65, 59, 28]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'lat': [90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0],
    'lon': [0.0, 12.5, 25.0, 37.5, 50.0]
})

res = df1.merge(df2, left_on='X', right_on='index').drop(columns='index')

print(res[['X', 'lat', 'lon', 'Y']])


Prints
   X   lat   lon    Y
0  0  90.0   0.0    1
1  0  90.0   0.0  125
2  1  90.0  12.5   65
3  1  90.0  12.5   59
4  2  90.0  25.0   28

